# Custom 404 - menu disappears

Tags: 7, theming, routes, debugging

I have created a custom 404 page using `hook_preprocess_page()`:

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $header = drupal_get_http_header('status');
  if($header == '404 Not Found') {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__404';
  }
}
```

The contents of `page--404.tpl.php` is identical to the contents of `page.tpl.php` except that use a static text block instead of calling `print render($page['content']);`. When this page is displayed one of the menus disappears from the header. Everything else look just as it does when I'm on a ordinary page except for the menu.

Since I only wan't to change the actual message that is displayed when receiving a `404` page and still use the rest of the markup contained in `page.tpl.php` perhaps it would be a better idea to only alter the `$page['content']` inside a hook or similar?

Would appreciate if anyone could help me figure out why the menu is vanishing or could give me a solution that only alters the `$page['content']` in `page.tpl.php` in case of a 404.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @AlvinPascoe - Yes, I did. In the end I used the `function hook_404()` to override the error message which in turn solved the problem. Not really sure why this happend from the beginning though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept using a module for this, rather than a theme override, you should be able to use [**CustomError**](https://www.drupal.org/project/customerror):

> This module allows the site admin to create custom error pages for HTTP status codes 403 (access denied) and 404 (not found), without the need to create nodes for each of them.

Just to make sure I've understood the use case: You write:

> Since I only wan't to change the actual message that is displayed when receiving a 404 page

This message is by default "Page not found  The requested page "..." could not be found. ".  I think **CustomError**' will reproduce the standard message unless you override this - but it may something about your use case that I have not understood.

Comment: I was considering this module, but I think it would be nicer to simply use some kind of preprocess hook. Seems like a litte too much to use a module for such a small task.

Comment: OK. I am curious about the resistance I've seen from developers (not only you) for using modules to solve problems. With proper caching (IMHO a *must* if you use Drupal in all sort of configurations), I've found that the performance (page bootstrap speed) is just as fast as adding a preprocess hook myself, and the memory footprint just a little bit larger.

Comment: That might very well be the truth but I'm also curious about **how** to simply modify the content of the page. I know I can use a module, but I would also like to learn how to do this by myself.

Comment: "I would also like to learn how to do this by myself".  I respect that.  Perhaps you should add this motivation to the question to make it clear to people trying to help you what it is your question *really* is about?  I clearly did interprete your statement "or could give me a solution" too broad.

Comment: +1 for @FreeRadical 's answer, and the related comments ... Why make it easy (using a module), if you can make it complicated also, right? I can understand one wants to use the opportunity to "learn" from such cases, but what about things like future maintenance (upgrades, etc) of custom modules? Other reasons for not using a contrib module I sometimes experience are (a) not knowing "there is a module for it", or (b) jobsecurity / jobprotection reasons ...

Comment: I don't think it's about making it complicated, it's about using the right tool to accomplish the task...and it's about avoiding unnecessary bloat. Why install a module (contrib or custom) when a few lines of code will get the job done. Modules are too many people's first stop when they want to tackle an issue. I always tend to look for a simple, module free option first. If the solution is too complicated, then I start looking at modules. The asker should be commended for asking about a non-module option, not berated (in my humble opinion ;) )

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to update your `THEME_preprocess_page` function to initialise a custom boolean variable based on whether the page returns a 404.

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $header = drupal_get_http_header('status');
  $variables['page']['page_not_found'] = false;
  if($header == '404 Not Found') {
    $variables['page']['page_not_found'] = true;
  }
}
```

You could then use this custom variable in your `page.tpl.php` (similar to how you check for `$logo` or `$site_title`) to display either the custom 404 text or `$page['content']`.

```
<?php if($page['page_not_found']): ?>
    <p>CUSTOM 404 TEXT</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would only recommend doing this if the 404 page contains *only* minor changes to a standard page. Otherwise, a different template file woild be the way to go.

Regarding the menu issue, I believe by default the primary links are hidden on 404 pages. This topic is discussed on drupal.org [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/249380#comment-902909), 'setvik' states the following solution:

To work-around the problem, do the following:

1) Create a custom node to handle "Page not found"'s.

2) go to Admin
-> Site Configuration -> Error Reporting and set the "Default 404 (not found) page:" to the node you just created.

I can vouch for this as I've had to do it myself numerous times in the past.